# Codeigniter HMVC + ciZacl login module attempt failing

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, hmvc

refs:

- https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home
- http://applications.schizzoweb.com/cizacl/user_guide/
- http://codecanyon.net/item/codeigniter-acl-user-management/407499

My Current Config:

- codeigniter 2.1.2
- clean install
- removed index.php via .htaccess
- installed modular extension via bitbucket mercurial repo
- configured clean database for cizacl
- attempted to convert cizacl to module [FAIL]

I believe the problem is in the __construct line 26, and the mapping to the correct file? ![image: error][image: code][image: Directory Structure]

Comment: remove the `if(!class....` and let's see if codeigniter throws any error when trying to load that class. And btw, with the hvmc module, you should use `MX_Controller` in your module's controller and not `CI_Controller`